Array won't appropriately curve to selection
I created a ruffle-like array from a cube and duplicated the vertical that I was using to connect it to. I set the cursor to the selection and the selection to the cursor, but my ruffles won't curve around the entire vertical. How do I fix this?


If you'd upload your blend file, people may be able to find a solution faster

At first sight, the only thing I can think of is that your curve is not (Alt-C) actually closed? https://imgur.com/a/dG1UWMl

i fixed it!! for anyone with the same ssue i had overlapping verticles!!
